# Prove $(1-\epsilon )\cdots(1-\epsilon ^{n-1})=n $ where $\epsilon = \exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n}), n\in \mathbb{N}, n \neq {0,1}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a problem with proving the following:
$$(1-\epsilon )\cdots(1-\epsilon ^{n-1})=n,$$
where
$$\epsilon = \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right), n\in \mathbb{N}, n \neq {0,1}.$$
I tried to use fact that
$$x^n-1=(x-1)\left(x-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)\right)\dotsm\left(x-\exp\left(\frac{(n-1)\cdot 2\pi i}{n}\right)\right).$$
When we divide RHS by $(x-1)$ on LHS we get $\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}$, which is the sum of the geometric series with first term $1$ and on the RHS almost desired expresion—the only problem is that if $x=1$ then LHS explodes.

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $1,\epsilon, \epsilon^2, \ldots, \epsilon^{n-1}$ are roots of $x^n=1$. Hence,
$$(x^n-1) = (x-1)(x-\epsilon)(x-\epsilon^2)\cdots(x-\epsilon^{n-1})$$
This gives us
$$\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1} = (x-\epsilon)(x-\epsilon^2)\cdots(x-\epsilon^{n-1}).$$
Since the right-hand side is continuous, we can calculate it by  taking the limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1}(x-\epsilon)(x-\epsilon^2)\cdots(x-\epsilon^{n-1}).$$
By l'Hôpital's rule,
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1} = \left.\dfrac{d(x^n)}{dx} \right \vert_{x=1} = n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice how the polinomial without the factor $(x-1)$ is continuous. Try taking the limit of the rational function you stated i.e. $ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$